# Yii2: how to use priority with andWhere and orWhere?

Tags: yii2, where-clause, query-builder

I have a Yii2 query but I have the problem with the `orWhere` Yii sentence.

I need persons where:

- **age is under 21**.
- `OR` **age is above 21** `AND` **first name is John**.

This is my code. I don't know how to use parenthesis for priority in Yii2:

```
Persons::find()
    ->select([Persons::tableName().".[[first_name]]"])
    ->where(['<', 'age', 21])
    ->orWhere(['>', 'age', 21])
    ->andwhere([Persons::tableName().".[[first_name]]" => 'John'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use one array with proper nesting:

```
Persons::find()
    ->select([Persons::tableName() . ".[[first_name]]"])
    ->where([
        'or',
        ['<', 'age', 21],
        [
            'and',
            ['>', 'age', 21],
            [Persons::tableName() . ".[[first_name]]" => 'John'],
        ],
    ]);
```

`andwhere()` and `orWhere()` are always appended new condition to the existing conditions, so you will get something like:

```
(((<first condition>) AND <second condition>) OR <third condition>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for your query:

```
Persons::find()
    ->select(["first_name"])
    ->where(['<', 'age', 21])
    ->orWhere("age > 21 AND first_name LIKE 'John'")
    ->all();
```

The query that will be generated based on above code:

```
SELECT `first_name` FROM `persons` WHERE (`age` < 21) OR (age > 21 AND first_name LIKE 'John').
```